# import xlsx bulk data java

Tags: java, excel

I have 1 million records of data in an excel sheet. Client requirement is to convert this file into csv format.

I tried the following set of code,

```
File src = new File("C:\\test.xlsx")
File dest = new File("C:\\test.csv")
src.renameTo(dest);
```

This is converting the file. But when i am opening i am getting error when opening the file.

Also, i tried the following code,

```
class XlstoCSV 
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            File inputFile = new File("C:\test.xls");
            File outputFile = new File("C:\output.csv");
              // For storing data into CSV files
    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
    try 
    {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

    // Get the workbook object for XLS file
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
    // Get first sheet from the workbook
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Cell cell;
    Row row;

    // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
    {
            row = rowIterator.next();
            // For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                    cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                    {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");
                            break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            data.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");
                            break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            data.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ",");
                            break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                            data.append("" + ",");
                            break;

                    default:
                            data.append(cell + ",");
                    }

                    data.append('\n'); 
            }
    }

    fos.write(data.toString().getBytes());
    fos.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

But my code is getting failed in this file,

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
```

I am getting Heap Memory error in the above line itself. I am not sure how to do bulk data upload by using java. I even tried Apache POI jar code. But that code is also failing.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Any reasons not to open the file in Excel and "Save As" csv?

Comment: @assylias thank you you just saved mytime

Comment: Is the file on server which is being dynamically updated ?

Comment: The file is on Server machine and the client wanted to convert it to CSV and we will have to move the file to client path so that the client can take the file from there

Comment: @madhunatarajan You will find something new here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap

Comment: 1048576 Total number of rows and columns on a worksheet. Are you telling it one sheet or diffrent files. i think 100 million records you cant save it in a sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to import the Excel file and [MapDB](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapdb/mapdb/0.9.0) to cache the rows in a disk-based file database.

Comment: Apache POI is also not working. There also i am getting it failed

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way (assuming the code works on smaller file): increase the memory used by the JVM.

Alternatively, you can write the file line by line:

```
Path outputFile = Paths.get("C:\output.csv");

HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

for (Row row : sheet) {
  List<String> csv = new StringBuilder();
  for (Cell cell : row) {
    //add the logic with csv.add(cell.getXXXValue()); etc., no comma here
  }
  String csvRow = String.join(",", csv) + "\n";
  Files.write(outputFile, csvRow.getBytes(UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}
```